# Problem with transformation of functions and simple logarithm

Tags: functions, logarithms

I am tackling a problem as below:

> $F(x)=\ln x$. The graph is transformed into a function $g$ by a translation
>   of $(3 , -2)$, followed by a reflection in the $x$-axis. Find an
>   expression for $g$, giving your answer as a single logarithm.

My thoughts are here:

After the transformation: $$g(x)=-\ln(x+3)-2$$
Then I tried to make it into a single logarithm: $$g(x)=-(\ln x+\ln 3)-2=-\ln3x-2$$

How can I change the digit 2 also into a logarithm form?? Help!

Comment: 2 is just $\ln(e^2)$.

Comment: Please read this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) about accepting an answer.

Comment: Come on, accept my answer if you're pleased with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your $g(x)$ isn't correct; it should be $-\ln(x-3)+2$. Now write $2=\ln e^2$, and the answer follows:
$$-\ln(x-3)+\ln e^2=\ln\frac{e^2}{x-3}$$

Comment: understood！sry for the late reply！

Comment: @何雨桓 Your reply isn´t late at all.